# Tests are hanging (ChutzpahTimeoutException)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, chutzpah

I've installed Chutzpah and ran it a couple of times in my computer, then I restarted and I get this sort of error when trying to run either from extension in *Visual Studio* or *command*:

```
>chutzpah.console /wait /path C:\Projects\CP\Testing\RESAAS.JavaScriptTestSuite\Specs

Chutzpah Error: Chutzpah.Exceptions.ChutzpahTimeoutException: Timeout occured when running C:\Projects\CP\Testing\RESAAS.JavaScriptTestSuite\Specs\User\RegistrationSpec.js
at Chutzpah.TestRunner.HandleTestProcessExitCode(Int32 exitCode, String inputTestFile) in c:\Dev\chutzpah\Chutzpah\TestRunner.cs:line 217
at Chutzpah.TestRunner.InvokeTestRunner(String headlessBrowserPath, TestOptions options, TestContext testContext, TestRunnerMode testRunnerMode, ITestMethodRunnerCallback callback) in c:\Dev\chutzpah\Chutzpah\TestRunner.cs:line 200
at Chutzpah.TestRunner.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ProcessTestPaths>b__1(PathInfo testFile) in c:\Dev\chutzpah\Chutzpah\TestRunner.cs:line 143
While Running:C:\Projects\CP\Testing\RESAAS.JavaScriptTestSuite\Specs\User\RegistrationSpec.js



Chutzpah Error: Chutzpah.Exceptions.ChutzpahTimeoutException: Timeout occured when running C:\Projects\CP\Testing\RESAAS.JavaScriptTestSuite\Specs\User\SendMessageSpec.js
at Chutzpah.TestRunner.HandleTestProcessExitCode(Int32 exitCode, String inputTestFile) in c:\Dev\chutzpah\Chutzpah\TestRunner.cs:line 217
at Chutzpah.TestRunner.InvokeTestRunner(String headlessBrowserPath, TestOptions options, TestContext testContext, TestRunnerMode testRunnerMode, ITestMethodRunnerCallback callback) in c:\Dev\chutzpah\Chutzpah\TestRunner.cs:line 200
at Chutzpah.TestRunner.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ProcessTestPaths>b__1(PathInfo testFile) in c:\Dev\chutzpah\Chutzpah\TestRunner.cs:line 143
While Running:C:\Projects\CP\Testing\RESAAS.JavaScriptTestSuite\Specs\User\SendMessageSpec.js

=== 0 total, 0 failed, took 0.00 seconds ===
```

If I click on a single test on one file in Visual Studio and ask it to run in browser it actually execute correctly, but since we got 100+ files I can't use this method for all files.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. It seems quite hard to find a reference online.

Comment: I see you posted the same issue here (http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/workitem/72). Can you attached a sample zip that I can repro your issue with there. That will help test and figure out your issue.

Comment: I actually can't share that by company policies, but my colleague running the same code base don't see the bug so I am really after any troubleshoot hint. @MatthewManela btw, I see that there is a new v2.2 but I don't see the download link in Codeplex.

Comment: 2.2.1 is http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/releases/view/96824.  If you can create a sample that is similar to your code that repros the issue that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @MatthewManela thanks a lot for the attention, but anyways even my colleague couldn't reproduce, so I think it is of little relevance, probably very localized with some bad file, I am pretty sure it is not even the tests themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just jumped back all the way to version 1.4 (to match my colleague) and the bug is all gone, since I am not using any new feature it is fine.

Answer (score 4):

In 2.0 version there is /timeoutMilliseconds option. Set this to a higher value, default is 5000 (ms)

Comment: It should be noted that the default is 3 seconds.  My build machine is taking right at 2-3 seconds, for some reason.  This fixed my problem!  +1

Comment: there's also a "TestFileTimeout" property in the chutzpah.json configuration file.